# dse graph - cassandra keyspace _pvt not created

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-enterprise-graph

```
$ bin/dse gremlin-console

         \,,,/
         (o o)
-----oOOo-(3)-oOOo----- 
plugin activated: tinkerpop.tinkergraph 
plugin activated: tinkerpop.server 
plugin activated: tinkerpop.utilities 
gremlin> system.graphs()
==>idg  gremlin>

$ bin/cqlsh -u dse_admin 
Password:  
Connected to dse_storm1 at
127.0.0.1:9042. [cqlsh 5.0.1 | DSE 6.0.1 | CQL spec 3.4.5 | DSE protocol v2] Use HELP for help.  dse_admin@cqlsh> desc keyspaces;

dse_system_local  
system_schema  
dse_leases  
system_distributed 
dse_security 
system_auth    
keyspace1   
system_traces            
system            
idg_system     
dse_perf    
idg           
dse_system 


dse_admin@cqlsh>
```

I am not able to see the keyspace idg_pvt

However, documentation says graph_pvt keyspace should also be created.
https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/graph/reference/refCassKSandTables.html

```
dse_admin@cqlsh:system_schema> select keyspace_name from keyspaces;

 keyspace_name
--------------------
                idg
        system_auth
      system_schema
   dse_system_local
         dse_system
         dse_leases
          keyspace1
 system_distributed
             system
         idg_system
           dse_perf
      system_traces
       dse_security
```

**Is the _pvt keyspace only created depending on the size of data loaded for vertices and edges? What is the threshold for DSE to create the _pvt keyspace and what is the impact to the cluster when _pvt keyspace is being created?**

Comment: Is the _pvt keyspace only created depending on the size of data loaded for vertices and edges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the version of DSE. In DSE 5.x, for every graph called `Name` three keyspaces were created: `Name`, `Name_system`, and `Name_pvt`.  In DSE 6.0, this changed, and only 2 keyspaces will be created `Name` and `Name_system`.

P.S. I've filed a ticket to fix documentation...

Comment: Thanks Alex for the clarification

Comment: I've got confirmation that this problem is fixed in next documentation snapshot (although I don't know when it will be published, hope, soon)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks.